# Jackson: Map Result Working Different on Server

Tags: java, json, hashmap, jersey, jackson

I am using jackson, I have a bean it is contain Map variable. This is my setter method:

```
Map<String, Integer> timeoutMap = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<JsonNode> dataIterator = response.get("data").iterator();
while(dataIterator.hasNext()){
    JsonNode data = dataIterator.next();
    String key = getValueAsString(data, "name");
    int value = getValueAsInteger(data, "timeout");
    if(!StringUtil.isNothing(key) && value > 0)
        timeoutMap.put(key, value);
}
TimeoutInfo timeoutInfo = new TimeoutInfo();
timeoutInfo.setTimeoutMap(timeoutMap);
```

My TimeoutInfo bean:

```
public class TimeoutInfo extends FrameworkResponse {

    public TimeoutInfo() {
        super(Constants.MODULE_CODE_COMMON);
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> timeoutMap;

    public Map<String, Integer> getTimeoutMap() {
        return timeoutMap;
    }

    public void setTimeoutMap(Map<String, Integer> timeoutMap) {
        this.timeoutMap = timeoutMap;
    }

}
```

When I run it on local server, my variable result as

```
"timeoutMap": {
    "Payment": 1000,
    "Thankyou": 500,
    "Profile": 1000
  }
```

But the same code working on server different. When I call it from server, my json structure is changing like this:

```
"timeoutMap": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "key": "Payment",
        "value": 1000
      },
      {
        "key": "Thankyou",
        "value": 500
      },
      {
        "key": "Profile",
        "value": 1000
      }
    ]
  }
```

My Jersey and Jackson Versions:

```
<jersey-version>2.23.2</jersey-version>
<jackson-version>2.4.6</jackson-version>
```

And I have this in my web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I think maybe JVM versions are different, and it caused this problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: please share your bean class and jackson version.

Comment: What's the server? Glassfish?

Comment: Server is Weblogic 12c